# Django Haystack - initial value for fields in overriden SearchForm not being displayed

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-haystack

On a site I've been running for years, I just upgraded both Django and Haystack from 1.11.5 and 2.6.1, respectively, to 2.0.5 and 2.8.1, respectively. Everything with the upgrade seems to have gone smoothly except that the `initial` values I'm providing in the overriden `SearchForm` are not being used anymore. I can't figure out why. I posted an issue on Haystack's issue tracker [here](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1605), but I haven't received a response, so I'm hopeful someone here might have some insight.

Here's the form:

```python
from haystack.forms import SearchForm

class SearchForm(SearchForm):                                            
    start_date = forms.DateField(initial=Post.get_first_post_timestamp(),
                                 input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])
    end_date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today,
                               input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])
    thread_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('All Types', 'All Types')] + Thread.get_sorted_unique_types_choices())
```

Here's the view:

```python
import haystack.generic_views

from apps.listserv.forms import SearchForm

class SearchView(haystack.generic_views.SearchView):
    template_name = 'listserv/search.html'
    form_class = SearchForm
    results_per_page = 10
```

Here's the template:

```html
...
[{{ form.start_date.value }}]

<form action="." method="get">
    <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Search: {{ form.q }}</p>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Dates: {{ form.start_date }} to {{ form.end_date }}</p>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Thread Type: {{ form.thread_type }}</p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><input type="submit" value="Search"></p>
</form>
...
```

Here's a screenshot of the resulting render:

[image: render]

As you can see, neither date is being displayed.

Note that prior to the upgrades, this *did* work. I'm wondering if something has changed between then and now in how `initial` parameters are handled with Haystack. I've checked the Django and Haystack changelogs pretty extensively, but nothing jumps out at me.

Does anyone have any guidance on this? Thanks!

**[EDIT - 2017-05-09]**
I just tried downgrading *only* Haystack back to 2.6.1, and this *does* work. So something must've changed with how Haystack's `SearchForm` handles `initial` parameters since then.

I did a little more debugging by trying each release listed [here](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/releases). 2.7.dev0 *works*, but 2.7.0 does *not*. So it looks like the bug I'm experiencing was introduced between those two versions. Note that I'm capturing all of this information on the issue I mentioned above ([here](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1605)).

Comment: actually, I don't think it has initial value like Django does, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16356799/5644965)

Comment: I haven't tried that yet because I'm not using `FacetedSearchView`, and I think that guidance is specific to that view. Furthermore, this *was* working up until this weekend when I tried the upgrade. Looking at the 2013 timestamp of that post, I'm not sure it applies to me. Although, perhaps the Haystack team modified `haystack.generic_views.SearchView` to behave more like `FacetedSearchView`?

Comment: FYI, I just tried downgrading *only* Haystack back to 2.6.1, and this *does* work. So something must've changed with how Haystack's `SearchForm` handles `initial` parameters since then.

Comment: great.. highlight it for curious people who will maybe stumble upon this question

Comment: Good call. Just added a blurb to the main post. Looking through Haystack's commits since 2.6.1 to see what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what's going on. After some debugging, I found the commit that introduced this bug (see https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1605#issuecomment-387938032 for specifics).

I've pointed the exact bug out to the Haystack guys, so hopefully they'll respond soon with a fix.